Text Recognition with pytesseract and cv2 or other libs
Please download the png file and save it as 'sample.png'.

I want to extract english characters in the png file.
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("sample.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 23, 100)
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 6")
res = ''.join(i for i in txt if i.isalnum())
print(res)

The output is
ee

Another try:
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/bin/tesseract'
image = cv2.imread('sample.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
inverted_image = cv2.bitwise_not(gray_image)
binary_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(inverted_image, 255, 
                                     cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
                                     cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
denoised_image = cv2.medianBlur(binary_image, 3)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4, 4))
eroded_image = cv2.erode(denoised_image, kernel)
mask = (denoised_image == 255) & (eroded_image == 0)
denoised_image[mask] = 0
cv2.imwrite('preprocessed_image.png', denoised_image)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(denoised_image, config='--psm 6')
print("result:", text.strip())

Get more accurate result than the first:
result:CRSP

It is 5 instead of S in the sample.png. How can I improve the code then?

Where is the number 5 then?

When working with images containing grid lines and noise, it's important to preprocess the image effectively to improve OCR accuracy. I've added some line removal, denoising, and text amplification. You might need to tweak the parameters a little bit but i've got the expected result from your sample image and also tried other samples with the same grid pattern, some different fonts and different colors and all worked correctly. You may need to change dilation kernel and line detection params to achieve a more accurate result.
Here's a Google Colab notebook for trial and error
Important Note: The reason that rizzling's code didn't work for you was the tesseract version. I have made sure the notebook linked above is using tesseract 5.4.1, which is the exact version i'm using on my machine

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Read the image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Removing gridlines (most important step)
    kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
    gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    
    # Thresholding
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    
    # Denoise
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(thresh)
    
    # Dilate
    kernel = np.ones((1,3),np.uint8)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(denoised, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    return dilated

def perform_ocr(image_path):
    # Preprocess the image
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image_path)
    
    # Configure Tesseract parameters
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    
    # Perform OCR
    try:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_image, config=custom_config)
        return text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during OCR: {str(e)}")
        return None

# Make sure you upload the image to colab for testing
image_path = 'sample.png'

# Perform OCR and get the text
extracted_text = perform_ocr(image_path)

if extracted_text:
    print("Extracted Text:")
    print(extracted_text)
else:
    print("Failed to extract text")

# Optional: Display the processed image
processed = preprocess_image(image_path)
plt.imshow(processed, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


To improve OCR recognition accuracy, I recommend the following approach:

Otsu's Thresholding: Automatically calculates the optimal threshold
for binarization, improving text visibility
Gaussian Blur: Smooths out noise without destroying edges, which
helps during OCR
Morphological Closing: Connects broken parts of characters, making
them more readable
Bilateral Filtering: Further reduces noise while preserving sharp
edges
Resizing: Upscaling the image gives Tesseract more pixel data to
work with, improving character recognition accuracy
Custom Configuration: Using tessedit_char_whitelist, we limit
recognition to English letters and digits, reducing confusion with
other symbols

(I made a kaggle notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/code/rayrizzling/text-recognition-with-pytesseract-and-cv2)
Disclaimer:
The approach outlined above works well with the provided sample.png and is optimized for recognizing images containing only capital letters and numbers. If the input image contains lowercase letters, special characters, or other elements outside this scope, additional adjustments to the preprocessing steps or the Tesseract configuration may be required. This method is tailored to simple cases, and more complex scenarios may need further fine-tuning for optimal results. Edit 14.12.24: Make sure to use the same module versions (which are used in the notebook example) when running the code in a different environment.
Here is the raw code:
import cv2
import pytesseract
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load the image
img_path = '/kaggle/input/example-ocr-png/M6ywO7up.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply Otsu's thresholding for binarization
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Apply Gaussian Blur to smooth the image
blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(binary_image, (3, 3), 0)

# Apply morphological closing to fill small gaps in characters
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
closed_image = cv2.morphologyEx(blurred_image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Apply bilateral filtering for further smoothing while preserving edges
smoothed_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(closed_image, 9, 75, 75)

# Resize the image to make the text more distinguishable
scaled_image = cv2.resize(smoothed_image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Perform OCR using Tesseract with a custom configuration
# - '--oem 3' uses the LSTM OCR engine
# - '--psm 6' assumes the image is a single block of text
# - 'tessedit_char_whitelist' limits recognition to alphanumeric characters
custom_config = '--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(scaled_image, config=custom_config)

# Outputs
print("Recognized Text:", text.strip())

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(scaled_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


You might also want to share the code of your notebook here, to make your answer more self-contained.

Good hint, done

I get the result :CRP with your method ,why the number 5 missing?

If you do this with the png you uploaded it will give CR5P as you can see in the notebook. the only reason for other results is when you do not use the exact same code or a different input image

@showkey i have faced the same problem when i was testing my working code on colab, it's because of the tesseract version, my code was missing 5 in version 4. see my answer and try the linked colab for my solution

tbh my answer was already correct. When you do not replicate the same code from the notebook (which obviously includes using the same versions) it's expectable that it might break with different versions. and furthermore colab was never mentioned in the scope of the question! @AxissXs  it's my bounty not yours.

@rizzling Well, i do not choose who gets the bounty. And it makes sense, questioner gives bounty to the response that solved his/her problem. you provided a kaggle link which is nice, and questioner asked why it doesn't work for him/her and you didn't point out the version (should the questioner use kaggle forever?), i did trial and error and found out what answers his/her question. and again, in the end, it's simply questioner's choice and what matters here is to provide solutions to problems, that's it.

I should get some glasses. sorry for that. I thought you asked the question as well. Anyway the question was not about the version conflict. And ofc he can use the env of his choice. But it should run on the same versions. That is such a basic the one who does not know this has clearly done zero research
